# Monitoring background image load pure javascript

Tags: javascript, load, background-image, monitoring

I have a simple code:

```
<div id="dk" style="background-image: url('d.jpg');"></div>
```

I would like to monitory this div loading and when it success do something and if the load take more then 5 seconds do otherthing.

I was trying to do :

```
document.getElementById('dk').addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
        //do something
    }, false);
```

But i belive that it works just for vídeos and áudios. Otherhand it will get just when it is complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this (untested):

```
function BackgroundLoader(url, seconds, success, failure) {
  var loaded = false;
  var image = new Image();

  // this will occur when the image is successfully loaded
  // no matter if seconds past
  image.onload = function () {
    loaded = true;
    var div = document.getElementById("dk");
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
  }
  image.src = url;      

  setTimeout(function() {
    // if when the time has passed image.onload had already occurred, 
    // run success()
    if (loaded)
      success();
    else
      failure();
  }, seconds * 1000);

}
```

and then use it:

```
<div id="dk"></div>
<script>
  function onSuccess() { /* do stuff */ }
  function onFailure() { /* do stuff */ }
  BackgroundLoader('d.jpg', 5, onSuccess, onFailure);
</script>
```

Comment: that is awesome... and i loaded jquery just to use .load()

Comment: This is nice. Great job mate.

Answer (score -2):

Change the event listener to the following:

```
document.getElementById('dk').addEventListener('load', function () {
    //do something
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I put an alert inside it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I read the question wrong, thought that was an image element. You can't put an onload listener on an individual div because it's not an external resource.